# OpenOffice predict number of days

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am counting my days of presence in Canada for citizenship purposes. The rule is that out of the last 1460 days you need to be present for 1095 days ( I am well aware of how poorly presence is defined but that's not on topic for this question.) I have a spreadsheet where each A cell contains the day when I left and each B cell contains the day I returned. I would like to count the date when I will have enough days. My problem is that I do not know which range of cells should be used for the calculation because that itself is dependent on the cells if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, success, Canada is beautiful! I felt at home whilst visiting (a perfect mix of Europe and the USA).

Let me know if this is what you are looking for?

[image]

[Canada Days.ods](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6572112/canada%20days.ods)

Comment: No, this calculates how many days I was out but not when out of the last 1460 days I have been in for 1095.

Comment: Another try, let me know if this comes closer?

Comment: Huh, I do not get this one :)

Comment: Well, then I suggest you make it clearer as to what it is you want! This shows the tally of the last 1460 days, which is automatically adjusted every day (rolling window)

Comment: Oh. If it's a rolling window great but I do not see most of the formulas in cells or get it how it works with the single one showing in the screenshot.

Comment: Added a link to the example file. You might have to change the formula's from `;`as field separator to `,`and the dates are (currently) in dd-mm-yyyy format.

Comment: That's great! There's one thing left... a goal seeker? on C2 so that F3 becomes 1095... I might be able to figure that one out.